# Upload public packages on gemfury

Tags: gem-fury

Using the `command line tool`, is there a way to upload package already `marked` as **public** ?

Answer (score 1):

An initial upload of a package to Gemfury will always be private. Once you've marked an uploaded package as public, all subsequently uploaded versions of that package will be public as well.

Answer (score 0):

You can do `fury push --public <file>`

```
Usage:
  fury push FILE

  Options:
      [--public], [--no-public]  # Create as public package
  -q, [--quiet], [--no-quiet]    # Do not show progress bar
      [--as=AS]                  # Access an account other than your own
      [--api-token=API_TOKEN]    # API token to use for commands
```